# Complex Object in aidl file having nested parceable

Tags: android, parcelable, aidl

I have developed one demo for IPC and use bounded servie to handle it....but facing some issue while using complex data structue( i.e. parceable inside parceable).
I am having the data structure like this...

**ObjectX.java**

```
 public class ObjectX implements Parcelable {

    private Integer code;
    private OtherEntity entity;

    public ObjectX(Integer _code, OtherEntity _entity) {

        code = _code;
        entity = _entity;
    }

    public ObjectX(Parcel source) {
        readfromParcel(source);
    }

    private void readfromParcel(Parcel source) {

        code = source.readInt();
        entity = (OtherEntity) source.readParcelable(OtherEntity.class
                .getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(code);
        dest.writeParcelable(entity, flags);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ObjectX> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ObjectX>() {
        @Override
        public ObjectX[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ObjectX[size];
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectX createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ObjectX(source);
        }
    };
}
```

**OtherEntity.java**

```
  public class OtherEntity implements Parcelable {
    private Integer m_code;

    public OtherEntity(Parcel source) {
        m_code = source.readInt();

    }

    public OtherEntity(Integer code) {
        m_code = code;

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(m_code);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<OtherEntity> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<OtherEntity>() {
        @Override
        public OtherEntity[] newArray(int size) {
            return new OtherEntity[size];
        }

        @Override
        public OtherEntity createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new OtherEntity(source);
        }
    };
}
```

And I have implemented Parcelable  in both the class..

My aidl files are :

**ObjectX.aidl:**

```
package com.example.demo.A;
parcelable ObjectX;
```

**IMyService.aidl:**

```
package com.example.demo.A;
import com.example.demo.A.ObjectX ;

interface IMyService {
    void setOrderData(in ObjectX data);
}
```

Now while setting data in object list like :

```
orderData.add(order);
```

passed as

```
mService.setOrderData(new Object(1,new OtherEntity(1));
```

I am getting this exception :

```
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.NullPointerException: expected receiver of type com.example.remoteservice.OtherEntity, but got null
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Field.getField(Native Method)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:269)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1955)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.example.remoteservice.ObjectX.readfromParcel(ObjectX.java:58)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.example.remoteservice.ObjectX.<init>(ObjectX.java:49)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.example.remoteservice.ObjectX$1.createFromParcel(ObjectX.java:94)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.example.remoteservice.ObjectX$1.createFromParcel(ObjectX.java:1)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Parcel.createTypedArrayList(Parcel.java:1616)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.example.remoteservice.IRemote$Stub$Proxy.getOrderData(IRemote.java:247)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.example.consumerapp3.RemoteServiceClient.onClick(RemoteServiceClient.java:95)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-20 15:35:28.018: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing ???

Comment: post `OtherEntity` class code

Comment: Is that all your stacktrace containinng ?

Comment: check new stack trace...

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your constructor `public Object(Parcel source)` get's a null value as source.

Comment: yeha getting error at `entity = (OtherEntity) source.readParcelable(OtherEntity.class.getClassLoader());` only..But count watch the parcle :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly fine, with things im assuming :

1. Your code to call AIDL method:

   ```
   mService.setOrderData(new Object(1,new OtherEntity(1));
   ```

means :

```
    mService.setOrderData(new ObjectX(1, new OtherEntity(1)));
```

2. AIDL file for OtherEntity has been created.

**OtherEntity.aidl** :

```
package com.example.demo.A;
parcelable OtherEntity;
```

Rest everything is working good. Hope it helps